# What's the difference between "Was this supposed to be...” and “Wasn't this supposed to be…"?

Tags: negation, auxiliary-verbs, interrogatives

> **Was** this supposed to be ‘cupboard’ instead of ‘cupbard’?
> **Wasn’t** this supposed to be ‘cupboard’ instead of ‘cupbard’?

I was asking about a spelling error and I was confused if I should use "was" or "wasn't". Which one is better and how are they different?

Comment: "Aren't you supposed to be doing your homework?"

Answer (score 20):

Let's look at a simpler example. Someone you haven't spoken to for a while phones you up, and you say *"Great to hear from you!"*...

> 1: *..."**Was** it a month ago when we last spoke?"*
> 2:   *..."**Wasn't** it a month ago when we last spoke?"*

OR
you're walking down the street with your friend, who says...

> 3: *"**Is** that your husband across the street there?"*
> 4: *"**Isn't** that your husband across the street there?"*

The negated versions more strongly imply speaker thinks the answer should probably be ***Yes***, but the non-negated versions don't really imply any "expected" answer.

Comment: +1, and even Shakespeare used this... "Isn't this a dagger which I see before me?" would have sounded very different from "Is this a dagger which I see before me?".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I asked chatgpt *Do any lines in shakespeare start with "Is this not..."?* - to which it replied *No, there are no lines in the works of William Shakespeare that start with the exact phrase "Is this not..." Shakespeare's plays and sonnets contain numerous memorable lines and phrases, but none of them begin with that.* Then I clicked "regenerate response, and it came back with *There is a line in Shakespeare's play "Hamlet" that starts with "Is this not": "Is this not the most high, majestic, and rightful Prince of Denmark?" (Hamlet, Act 2, Scene 2).* TOTALLY MADE UP!

Comment: +1 You can remove "I'd say". Your answer is correct ;)

Comment: @gotube: (I'd say :) you're quite correct! I *do* sometimes make mistakes. So I might say *it's **almost always** X* even when *in principle* I'd be perfectly familiar with ***Y*** and ***Z*** as far-from-unknown alternatives - which I just happened not to think of at the time because I'm not that mentally agile. But it's not really helpful to learners to spatter your answer with such weaselly disclaimers. I should perhaps take a leaf out of chatgpt's book - it *always* sounds supremely confident, even when when it's saying is completely fictitious "hallucination" as per previous comment!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Messing with ChatGPT's "brain": https://imgur.com/6J2MNg0

Comment: “The negated versions more strongly imply speaker thinks the answer…” Shouldn't that be… **the** speaker…?

Comment: Thank you so much. This really answered my question <3

Comment: @Mari-LouA: To some extent, dropping the article before "speaker" is a domain-specific usage among linguists (which I'm not one of, apart from one years study over 50 years ago, plus whatever I've picked up here and on ELU over the past decade). If you leaf through a few written instances of [***implies speaker***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22implies+speaker%22) in Google Books you'll see it's used quite often by competent writers within the field.

Comment: So omitting "the" was a deliberate choice, it wasn't a typo. I was thinking whether I should have edited but thought best to ask. OK. Interesting, I don't think it's sounds very good, or grammatical, but you're more of an expert than I could ever be.

Comment: I must have done it hundreds of times here and on ELU, but I *think* you might be the first person ever to mention it. Most of us wouldn't accept such things in other contexts, such as if you work on a supermarket checkout till, and your manager says *Press the "Call Supervisor" button **if customer** becomes aggressive*. (On the other hand, I've never had a job like that - perhaps they ***do*** drop the article there! :)

Comment: ...perhaps it's passed unremarked because most users here are either quite competent *native* Anglophones, or they're less experienced *learners* (who often struggle with articles in English). I don't think there are that many non-Anglophone users here with *your* level of competence - one that comes to mind is Janus Bahs Jacquet, but he's got quite a background in linguistics anyway!

Comment: ...perhaps one of us should raise this usage as a question on ELL, just so we can direct others to it as and when appropriate. There's not much point in me trying to change my usage pattern, since there will always be at least *some* others doing it even on the site itself - plus now and then we'll be directing learners to domain-specific texts where it's actually *common*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Formal instructions such as "Press 'Call Supervisor' if customer becomes aggressive" is actually specifically somewhere I might expect the article to be omitted (but only really if it were given in writing). In such cases, brevity might be considered more important than being strictly grammatical. In more of a conversational sentence, it sounds very odd.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Sure. But that's why I very specifically wrote *and your manager **says...*** Of course, we might then have to consider the status of the texts we write here on ELL. In which context your "conversational sentence" looks useful - I'd say most if not all of what we write here is "conversational", even though the medium is writing, not speech. Bottom line: me dropping the article before words like *speaker, reader, subject,...* is probably unhelpful and I should try to get out of the habit. But I'll still usually write OP rather than **the** OP (I don't write "**the** NotThatGuy"! :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer by FumbleFingers is correct about the difference in meaning:

https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/337837/48147

The negative carries an implied presumption of "correctness", whereas without the negative it comes across as an actual question to be answered.

However, there is an additional implication, which I think is stronger in your specific case than in the examples in the other answer, which is that "wasn't" seems to imply this was *something you already discussed* or *something they should have already known*.

I would recommend using:

> Was this supposed to be cupboard instead of cupbard?

in your specific case if you mean to show politeness about the error and allow the author to correct it; by making it a question you're sort of indicating it's an easy error anyone could make and prompting them to re-check their work.

I would recommend using:

> Wasn't this supposed to be cupboard instead of cupbard?

if you have already discussed this and came to an agreement that the correct spelling is "cupboard" but your coworker keeps stubbornly spelling it a different way and you are frustrated with them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation and for taking time answering this. I appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

The second form, “Wasn’t it ...?” is a rhetorical question.  You expect the answer to be “yes.”

The first form, in written English, is a normal question that could be answered either way.  In spoken English, you’d use different of tones of voice to hint that you think the person ought to disagree, that they ought to agree, or that you’re sincerely uncertain.  You might indicate those with emphasis: “*Was* this supposed to be cupbard?” should be read aloud with the word *was* in a higher pitch, to mention only one way.  You could also indicate this through word choice: “Was this really supposed to be ...?”

In this context, pointing out a student’s spelling mistake, making it into a rhetorical question was probably intended as a more polite way of saying, “You misspelled ‘cupboard.’”  This further implies that the writer did know, and just made an accidental, minor typo.  But the teacher doesn’t want to leave any ambiguity about whether it’s an error.  Therefore, I think “wasn’t” is clearer.  However, in many other situations, a rhetorical question could come across as rude, or even sarcastic.  So use them with care.  The “was” variant is gentler, but doesn’t communicate as clearly that there is a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much. This would help me choose better words in the future :)